# What is the key.subkey syntax for Puppet 3.x?

Tags: puppet, hiera

> In Puppet and Hiera, you often need to work with structured data in
>   hashes and arrays.
>
> In the Puppet language, you can access hash and array members with
>   square brackets, like $facts['networking']['fqdn']. Hiera doesn’t use
>   square brackets; instead, it uses a key.subkey notation, like
>   facts.networking.fqdn.

This is for 5.2. Is there the same functionality available in 3.8? I could not find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there the same functionality available in 3.8?

No.  Puppet 3 -- which is obsolete and no longer supported -- uses Hiera version 1, which does not support the key / subkey syntax.  You need at least Puppet 4 / Hiera 3 for that, but even that's very old.  The latest Puppet is v6.4 (with Hiera 5).